# How do I style Stripe credit card fields with AngularJS integrated?

Tags: css, angularjs, stripe-payments

I have integrated AngularJS with a sign up form that includes Stripe.

Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063641/1435711

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/JakeballBase/ubgkforL/

Only downside is the background of the Stripe fields are transparent. How do I make the background white with rounded border corners? Like this CSS style:

```
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.375rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripe fields are transparent so that you can apply the background color to the parent element. You just need to apply the styles to `stripe` tag.

```
stripe {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.375rem;
}
```